# Can't click OK to change qtcreator to use tabs for C++

Tags: qt-creator

In qtcreator's Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> Behavior there's tabs and spaces settings. This doesn't affect C++.

Instead, the coding style needs to be set in Tools -> Options -> C++ -> Coding Style -> Edit -> General.

The problem is, after changing to tabs I can't click OK. The button appears to be broken. I can shift-tab to the Cancel button, but arrow keys to select OK just start editing the example code panel.

How can this be done?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the "built-in" coding styles can't be edited. Why it allows you to click "Edit" in the first place I don't know. Anyway, in Tools -> Options -> C++ -> Coding Style, click Copy to create your own style. Then Edit and change the settings.